# not redirected to login page when session timed out with ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having many ajax calls in my website which is build using mvc3 razor.
Problem is that after session has timed out if call is made to action using ajax then it is not redirected to login page.
I am handling session timeout using attribute which is shown bellow.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) 
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

       //  check if session is supported
        if(ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            if (ctx.Session != null)
            {

                // check if a new session id was generated
                if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {

                    // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                    // have timed out
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if (null != sessionCookie)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        const string loginUrl = @"~/Login/Login";
                        var rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                       filterContext.Result = rr;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {

            ctx.Response.Redirect(@"~/Login/Login");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
    }
```

Comment: search for questions related to yours before asking them yourself. Most of the times you will get them.

Answer (score 1):

The result which you are passing will be sending an html page and a 302 to the ajax request as the response. There are other ways to handle this :

1. Give a custom Response code and check it in the ajax request and check the response code in the success function.
2. Or Else send a json object containing a response object and check it in there

This can be done at the ajaxComplete event for both the methods and could be added to the Master Page / Layout or wherever there are ajax calls.

**Not pasting in code since its there on many other questions .**
Welcome to StackOverflow Vaibhav !